# Making Armadillo C++ library fast in Linux - Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, armadillo

Originally a user from Windows, I am using Ubuntu OS via VirtualBox, with GCC 9.30 installed on the Ubuntu OS. I installed Armadillo, BLAS and LAPACK using the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
sudo apt-get install libarmadillo-dev
```

Afterwards I created the following .cpp file, which measures time taken to perform 20 multiplications of 500 x 500 matrices:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;


int main() 
{
    chrono::steady_clock sc;
    int n = 500;
    arma::Mat<double> A = arma::randu(n, n);
    arma::Mat<double> B = arma::randu(n, n);
    auto start = sc.now();     // start timer

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        arma::Mat<double> C = A * B;
    }
    auto end = sc.now();
    auto time_span = static_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(end - start);
    cout << "Operation took: " << time_span.count() << " seconds !!!";
    return 0;
}
```

I run the file from the Linux terminal using the following command

```
g++ armaC.cpp -o armaC -O3 -march=native -fopenmp -larmadillo
```

And this turns out to be incredibly slow at 1.5 seconds on average, while MATLAB takes around 0.08s. In fact, removing the command -O3 or -fopenmp doesn't seem to change the speed at all, which seems to indicate that something is very wrong in my compiling method.

I also tried running it with the following line in the terminal, which should include the BLAS and LAPACK packages in the mix:

```
g++ armaC.cpp -o armaC -llapack -lblas
```

This gives me the following error:

[image]

Could somebody give me some help on this please?

Comment: Likely due to "reference" (== single-threaded, unoptimised) BLAS.  Install a different BLAS and LAPACK pair.  Atlas can be tuned. OpenBLAS is multithreaded,  You really _are_ comparing apples and oranges as Matlab ships with the MKL (which you can install too:  https://github.com/eddelbuettel/mkl4deb.  I find that OpenBLAS is preferable (much smaller, almost as fast).

Comment: There is a note in Armadillo documentation, `when using GCC, use of -march=native in conjunction with -fopenmp may lead to speed regressions on recent processors.` Also `auto` is not recommended to use in Armadillo.

Answer (score 3):

Standard BLAS and LAPACK are reference implementations which are slow.
It's much faster to use an accelerated version like [OpenBLAS](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/releases) or [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/math-kernel-library.html).

Before installing Armadillo, first install OpenBLAS.  This can be done manually by using the archive directly from the OpenBLAS page, or automatically through a package manager.

For example, on Ubuntu 20.04 use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-openmp-dev
```

... and then reinstall Armadillo.  It's generally recommended to use the [most recent version](http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html) available.

To address your linking issues, see Armadillo's [Questions](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) page.

(NB: on Ubuntu 20.04, don't install `libopenblas-serial-dev` or `libopenblas-dev`. These are buggy. Remove them from your system. Only `libopenblas-openmp-dev` works properly.)

Comment: How would you uninstall Armadillo and reinstall it in ubuntu. I haven't found a way.

Comment: @AlejandroAndrade A workaround is use a command line like `g++ -O3 -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER test.cpp -lopenblas`: do not use `-larmadillo`.